# OSB Proxy Based Logging

Tags: soa, osb

Is there any way to create separate log files based on Proxy services?

http://carlgira.blogspot.in/2014/07/osb-custom-proxy-logging.html

The above url provides some info. But that seems not working. We require something as in what is described in url.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hi Trent-   When application runs, logs are written on osb_server1.log file[Server log]. Thing is that we want to have proxy service based logging. If the proxy service name is A, log will be written on A.log file. If it's B, it'll be written on B.log file. There should be some filter that will filter logs for A/B Proxy service from osb_server1, writing the same on A.log file if Proxy service name is A or B.log file if Proxy service name is B.

Comment: OK, but why? Is it for traffic stats? Auditing? Operational support?

Answer (score 1):

The report is a way to do it, but if you are going to use that option i would recommend to create a custom report provider.

The solution on the blog (the blog entry is mine) tries to use a startup-class of weblogic to modify the order of the loggers so you can add a custom one, before the real one.

There is a second blog entry with more detail and the **complete maven sources** in github.

The blog entry http://carlgira.blogspot.com.es/2015/05/weblogic-filter-logs.html

The github sources https://github.com/carlgira/soa-utils/tree/master/weblogic-custom-logging

Comment: Thanks Carlos for answering back. Actually I tried to create seperate log files based on the proxy service name. I followed you doc, and it's working fine, creating separte log files based upon proxy service name, provided you have to enable trace in the said proxy services. Is there any other way to log without enabling trace in proxy services?

Comment: OSB has a `Log` action. You will need to log something for the filter to filter on, though, so you'll need to format the output with `tokenize($inbound/@name,'\$')[2]` and `$operation` into a format that the filter can understand

Comment: Thanks Trent...Do you have any sample java example for this? If so, pls share it so that the java code can filter out log messages, and based upon  message body,it can log.

Comment: Suvra if you dont activate the tracing of the proxy you are not going to see any information on the logs. (using or not the filter).

Comment: Hi Carlos- That's correct. Tracing allows messages to be written on log files. But we dont want to enable tracing because we have already log action in place for proxy services writing logs on server log files in an xml format having proxy/business services name. We just want to have any custom java program to read these messages from log files and write to a separate log file.That's our requirement.

Comment: Ok, i understand. You need that your log activities also get filtered, for that, the only thing you need to do, is to append to your log activities the configured Weblogic filter. In your case just append "[OSB Tracing]" to every log activity, also append the proxy-name so you can get it and use it as logger to create a file for every proxy (thats not in the sample so you'll have to do it yourself)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.I am able to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log the request and the response for single proxy service , then you can go for Report Action.

Here , you can do reporting for single operations and proxy service.

Comment: No single proxy, we have multiple proxy services. want to have separate log files for each proxy services to have more visibilities and easy to search mechanism.